# grouping array of objects by two variables with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following data structure:

```
[
{ date: 12.12.20,
  country: Italy,
  categoryType: one
},
{ date: 12.12.20,
  country: Germany,
  categoryType: one
},
{ date: 15.12.20,
  country: France,
  categoryType: two
}
]
```

I am trying to group by two variables: (1) date and then, within each date (2) group type by country.

I succeeded in grouping by date, but I am not sure how to group category by country.

I want to have the following, preferably with lodash.js:

```
        [
        { date: 12.12.20,
          country: [
         Italy: [categoryType: one],
         Germany: [categoryType: one]]
}, 
    {...}]
```

Here is my code

```
_.chain(data)
          .groupBy('date')
          .map((dates, date)=> {
            const country = _.map(dates, 'country');
           
            return {
               date: date,
               country: country,
          }
        }).value()
```

Comment: Doesn't the argument passed to `groupBy` need to be a function?

Comment: it would be good if you can provide sample desired output.

Comment: I have included an example of what a final structure should look like (i think). Its the second code snippet. Not sure if this is clear though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
const data = [
  {
    date: "12.12.20",
    country: "Italy",
    categoryType: "one"
  },
  {
    date: "12.12.20",
    country: "Germany",
    categoryType: "one"
  },
  {
    date: "15.12.20",
    country: "France",
    categoryType: "two"
  }
]

console.log(
  _.mapValues(
    _.groupBy(data, 'date'),
    e => _.groupBy(e, 'country')
  )
)
```

This should yield the desired output:

```
{
  '12.12.20': {
    'Italy': [
      {
        'date': '12.12.20',
        'country': 'Italy',
        'categoryType': 'one'
      }
    ],
    'Germany': [
      {
        'date': '12.12.20',
        'country': 'Germany',
        'categoryType': 'one'
      }
    ]
  },
  '15.12.20': {
    'France': [
      {
        'date': '15.12.20',
        'country': 'France',
        'categoryType': 'two'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! However, the result is not exactly what I had in mind I think. I would still need a country key and then a name of a country as a value. To be able to access it with country.name. And then if I have multiple countries per date, it doesn't seem that categories are nested per each country. I attached a picture that hopefully would make this more clear. Basically, I would want a system: parliament to be inside a corresponding country. Really hope this explanation makes sense.  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/29S6f.png